# PHP/HTML: Mobile website to desktop website using mobile device

Tags: php, html, mobile

I've expanded my website by adding a 'mobile device detector' to it, so that is will send you to a different page when you're using a mobile device (check it out [here](http://ysbakker.eu/beta), and for the mobile version [here](http://ysbakker.eu/beta/mobile) (of course it will automatically send you there when using a mobile device if you clicked the first link. Note: If it's not working, let me know!)

Now anyways, I ran into an issue. At the mobile website, I want to add a way to switch to the desktop version (also the other way around). I found that this couldn't be possible without a variable to store that in, or the server would have to many redirects. Now, I can't find a way to do that thing. I've already tried deploying the php `$_POST['']` method and the php `$_GET['']` one, but I can't find where and how to use it.

Thanks!

EDIT: As requested, here's the code where I detect devices:

```
<?php $useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4))) header('Location: http://www.ysbakker.eu/beta/mobile'); ?>
```

Well, I must say that I didn't make this myself, but downloaded the thing from a website.

Here's the code on the mobile page that detects again, but this time if it's not true:

```
<?php
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(!preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od|ad)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: http://www.ysbakker.eu/beta');
?>
```

Comment: Use session for saving their settings temporary. Give us piece of your code where you detect devices

Comment: or you could use cookies to keep that decision for years.

Comment: Well, thanks for the advice, but could you also give me an example of how to use those? Because I'm completely out of ideas...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about if you call:

```
header('Location: http://www.ysbakker.eu/beta?mode=desktop');
```

Then check in your page:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['mode']))
     {
        if($_GET['mode'] == 'desktop')
        {
          //show desktop version here
        }else if($_GET['mode'] == 'mobile')
        {
          //show mobile version here
        }
     }
?>
```

Then ensure that you tell both versions of your website (desktop and mobile) that if this $_GET param exists in the request, then ignore all useragent checks like so:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_GET['mode'])
  {
    //perform useragent check here
  }
?>
```

Comment: So... At the mobile site I put as the header location http://ysbakker.eu/beta?mode=desktop in case the device isn't mobile? And then it executes the php code you gave... So at the point it says "show your desktop version here" I put in the header location of the desktop version and the same with mobile? But then I would have the same issue right... That it redirects me unlimitedly... Sorry for not getting it :(

Comment: you are correct. I edited my answer, check again and lemme know if that works for you.

Comment: Wait, there's an issue. I now put the code in both of the files (of course customized so that it should work) but now, when I go to the mobile version from the desktop version, it will redirect me back to the desktop site... Help!

Comment: EDIT: Never mind, I fixed it already. Turns out that you don't have to fill in the header location of the page you're currently at, or it will infinitely redirect you. Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Simply check if the referrer is coming from within your site. If they are, they have already seen a page and have chosen where they want to go next or have been redirected:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'yoursite.com')===false){
//Check for mobile and provide a mobile link (or perform redirect here)
}
```

Full example with mobile device detection and redirect:

```php
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'yoursite.com')===false){
$useragent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i',$useragent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($useragent,0,4)))
header('Location: https://www.yoursite.com/mobile/');
}
?>
```

Comment: Around the code that you use to check if the user is using a mobile device which will usually be somewhere near the start of your code or right at the start, before any other output, if you will be doing any redirect.

Comment: Please sir, can you paste that entire little code, so everyone to understand better?

Comment: I strongly recommend you look into using CSS3 media queries that will enable you to use one codebase and modify the look of the pages based on the screen resolution/viewport width being used rather than trying to provide and maintain two versions of the same website. It will save you a lot of problems in the future. If this is simply not possible, I have added a method to the answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. So your code, should be place on the desktop html page, in order to redirect to mobile page, correct ? And the final ('Location: https://www.yoursite.com/mobile/') will make a redirection to the mobile page?

Comment: Yes, the first `yoursite.com` should be the FQDN only and the second `yoursite.com` URL should be the location to redirect mobile users to.

Comment: the last thing, I copy your php code at the beginning of one of my html file, and I replace the mobile Location for a different domain from the first one. I haven't made a subdomain yet  such as `https://m.yoursite.com/`, so I put with a random domain such as  `https://m.other-mobile-site.com/`. That's why I cannot see the changes and the redirection ?

Comment: It will attempt to load the redirected URL regardless of whether it exists or not provided your browser is using a recognised `HTTP_USER_AGENT` string, which is something that needs keeping up-to-date. I have just tested this snippet and it is working. Note that `HTTP_REFERER` is not set by all user agents so I have added a check for this. Again, this is not foolproof and CSS3 media queries are the way to go.

Comment: where should I make these settings, with `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and `HTTP_REFERER` ? In apache / .htaccess file ? Or directly into the php code ?

Comment: They are predefined PHP variables based on the information supplied by the web browser and the code checks them for matches, redirecting if a mobile device is detected. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php